# Android - layer-list oval shape has extra inner line

Tags: android, xml, layer-list

I have created a layer-list but its not perfect. Here is the layer-list in android xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="200dp"
                android:height="200dp" />
            <solid android:color="#5BB534" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="25dp"
        android:top="25dp"
        android:right="25dp"
        android:bottom="25dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#4335BA" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="30dp"
        android:top="30dp"
        android:right="30dp"
        android:bottom="30dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="20dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="#BFB637" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and here is where i am applying the layer list:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mylayerlist"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv"/>
```

Here is the final product:

[image]

notice there is this line sticking inside the circle. i just want a perfect circle. i want it to look like this (more or less,just get rid of the little line sticking out):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try with innerRadius.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="200dp"
                android:height="200dp" />
            <solid android:color="#5BB534" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="25dp"
        android:top="25dp"
        android:right="25dp"
        android:bottom="25dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#4335BA" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        >
                <shape
                    android:innerRadius="100dp"
                    android:shape="ring"
                    android:thickness="20dp"
                    android:useLevel="false">
                    <solid android:color="#BFB637" />

                </shape>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Or, you can always have some happy drawing on canvas, creating customview.

Comment: can you tell me what this block of xml code does: <item
        android:left="25dp"
        android:top="25dp"
        android:right="25dp"
        android:bottom="25dp">   what exactly does it mean to have an item with these boundaries, does it mean to create a rectangle with this measurements ?

Comment: rectangle with padding 25dp and size of the view. It should work using your approach, but it seems to be a little buggy

Answer (score 2):

```
To create a ring like Layered List.


XML Code

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">

            <solid
                android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

            </solid>

            <size
                android:width="30dp"
                android:height="30dp">

            </size>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@android:color/white">
            </stroke>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="15dp"
        android:right="15dp"
        android:top="15dp"
        android:bottom="15dp">

        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid
                android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

[image]